# Does the word "listicles" exist?

Tags: meaning, is-it-a-word

I can't find the word "listicles" in my English dictionary and I would like to know if it exists please.

Comment: Go to google.com. Type in `define listicles`.

Comment: "a piece of writing or other content presented wholly or partly in the form of a list."

Comment: related http://english.stackexchange.com/q/124688/168678

Answer (score 2):

From [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/36354548): "A journalistic article or other piece of writing presented wholly or partly in the form of a list. *Frequently depreciative.*"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, and thanks for a detailed answer. I'd like to inform you that one-liner questions that show no research effort usually get closed and eventually deleted. Please try to answer well-asked questions. :)

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. Slowly learning my way around. Found the FAQs but not found a good newbies guide yet.